# Argument of \posttitle has an extra }

Tags: memoir, titles

According to the texdoc for the [memoir class](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf), page 63 and 64, the usual `\maketitle` command is:

```
\newcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \vspace*{\droptitle}
  \maketitlehooka
  {\pretitle \title \posttitle}
  \maketitlehookb
  {\preauthor \author \postauthor}
  \maketitlehookc
  {\predate \date \postdate}
  \maketitlehookd
  \thispagestyle{title}
}
```

So I would think that entering that in place of `\maketitle` should work. But when I do this, I get the error "Argument of \posttitle has an extra }".

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\title{Hello}

%\maketitle

\vspace*{\droptitle}
\maketitlehooka
{\pretitle \title \posttitle}
\maketitlehookb
{\preauthor \author \postauthor}
\maketitlehookc
{\predate \date \postdate}
\maketitlehookd
\thispagestyle{title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The description in the manual is a little bit inaccurate or better, it says `essentially`.  It is actually ` \maketitlehooka
  {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}` where `\@bsposttitle` etc. are macros defined by `\posttitle{foo}` etc. I.e. `\posttitle` and the other macros all require an argument, which is missing in your example

Comment: Thanks Christian, but I'm not quite getting it. Would you mind writing an answer with working code? I just want more control over my title page.

Answer (score 6):

The `memman` (memoir manual) says on pages 63/64

> ```
> The class provides a configurable \maketitle command. The \maketitle command
> as defined by the class is essentially
> ```

```
\newcommand{\maketitle}{%
\vspace*{\droptitle}
\maketitlehooka
{\pretitle \title \posttitle}
\maketitlehookb
{\preauthor \author \postauthor}
\maketitlehookc
{\predate \date \postdate}
\maketitlehookd
\thispagestyle{title}
}
```

However, the real code in `memoir.cls` is

```
\newcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \let\footnote\@mem@titlefootkill
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\z@
    \newpage
  \fi
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
        \vspace*{\droptitle}
  \maketitlehooka
  {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
  \maketitlehookb
  {\@bspreauthor \@author \@bspostauthor}
  \maketitlehookc
  {\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate}
  \maketitlehookd
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

where `\@maketitle` is actually called inside `\maketitle`.

In fact, `\@bspretitle` etc. are used, not `\pretitle` etc, which have similar definitions:

```
\newcommand{\pretitle}[1]{\def\@bspretitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\posttitle}[1]{\def\@bsposttitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\preauthor}[1]{\def\@bspreauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\postauthor}[1]{\def\@bspostauthor{#1}}
\newcommand{\predate}[1]{\def\@bspredate{#1}}
\newcommand{\postdate}[1]{\def\@bspostdate{#1}}
```

Now, `\pretitle` etc. are macros that use one argument, inside they define something like `\@bspretitle`, so `\pretitle` etc. can't be used directly without an argument.

Basically, it is sufficient to use `\pretitle{something}\posttitle{other thing}`, but this must be handled we care, see for example (also on page 64 of the manual) the default definitions in `memoir` are

```
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}
\large \lineskip 0.5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\postauthor{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}
\predate{\begin{center}\large}
\postdate{\par\end{center}}
```

where `\posttitle{foo}` without adjusting `\pretitle` would leave an error, since `\pretitle` is defined as `\begin{center}` basically, so there would be an unclose `center` environment, causing compilation errors.

This code defines a group begun in `\pretitle`, with `\bfseries` and an ending group in `\posttitle`, with some `\LARGE` text lead-in.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\pretitle{\begingroup\bfseries}
\posttitle{ \LARGE This is from \textbackslash\texttt{posttitle} \endgroup}
\title{Hello}


%\maketitlehookb{\preauthor \author \postauthor{foobar}}
%\maketitlehookc{\predate \date \postdate{foodate}}
%\maketitlehookd{\thispagestyle{title}}


\maketitle

\vspace*{\droptitle}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the real code in the memoir class doesn't work either. I wanted control over my title page, but I have no idea how to do it.

I guess I asked the wrong question. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @DavidSpivak: You have the control... and no one forces you to use `\maketitle` at all. I have updated my answer with the last relevant code pieces from `memoir` .... Defining just one of `\pretitle` or `\posttitle` is not enough -- both of the 'pair' must be adjusted

Comment: The `titling` package contains the same kind of misleading description. I didn't realise Memoir did the same.

Comment: @cfr: Interesting -- I never used the `titling` package on intention... perhaps only accidentally if providing a solution (if any at all). So `titling` was perhaps modeled after `memoir` and its documentation?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Or the other way around? I'm not sure. As I say, I didn't know Memoir did this. I use `titling` all the time and I remember being misled in something like this way, too.

Comment: @cfr: Ah, now I see: `memoir` and `titling` were originally from the same author ... that could explain the similarity

Comment: `The memoir class includes code either equivalent to, or extensions of, the following packages; that is, the set of commands and environments is at least the same as those in the packages: ... titling ...` (xxix of Memoir's manual). The interface is very, very similar, if not identical (I haven't checked).

Comment: @cfr: I did not check as well, but I suspect it happens in the sometimes very dreadful 'emulation' way of `memoir`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\begin{center}` in  argument of `\pretitle`, use `\centering`. Also remove `\end{center}` from `\postitle`. Similarly add `\centering` in `\preauthor` and `\predate`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you test your changings? Can you please show us that test code for a fast proof?